# Ping from VRF VLAN interface

Tags: networking, ping

I'm working on configuring multiple VRFs on Ubuntu Server 16.10 and having trouble using ping to validate the configuration. I've been using https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/vrf.txt for reference.

My configuration is:

Server:
eth0.20 - 192.168.20.50/24 - GW 192.168.20.1

Router:
port1(VLAN20) - 192.168.20.1/24

From the router, I can ping the server address at 192.168.20.50. The arp entry on the router for the server is correct and tcpdump on the server confirms pings are hitting eth0.20.

However, the server can't ping 192.168.20.1. It does have an ARP entry for the router interface which makes me think this is an issue with how I'm using being. Below is the ping and resulting output.

```
ping -I red 192.168.20.1
ping: Warning: source address might be selected on device other than red
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable


ping -I eth0.20 192.168.20.1
ping 192.168.20.1 (192.168.20.1) from 192.168.20.50 eth0.20: 56(86) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable
```

Any assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: Since this iformation is missing on your question, have you assigned vlan id 20 to your `eth0.20` interface? `vconfig add eth0 5` and then `cat /proc/net/vlan/eth0.20` to double check vlan information... If you didn't assign vlan id, it will assume that is just an ordinary virtual interface.

Comment: I'm creating the VLAN in the /etc/network/interfaces file to be persistent. I did confirm that /proc/net/vlan/eth0.20 contains VID: 20.